# How to transferring files from SharePoint folder to another SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I am sorry if this is not the right place to put this question.

I have some files saved inside a SharePoint folder. Now I need to move them to a SharePoint site from that folder.

When I select the folder and select Move To option, I don't see the site in the list of available locations.

Please note, I am not supposed to take the download-upload approach. I have instructed to use the Move To option only.

By the way, I am using the Modern SharePoint UI.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Whether you have enough permission for the destination site collection?

Comment: I had the permission from the beginning, but I was not following the sites! Now everyting is fine. Thank you for taking time and considering my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move/copy files in sahrepoint to sharepoint you need to follow to destination else the site will not show to you while you move files.

[Follow sharepoint site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNnQ5.png)

Once you follow site, then the destination site will show when you select files to move.

Note: you should have enough permissions to move /Copy files in destination location.